# enabling IPython notebook rich display

Tags: python, ipython

I can't seem to get the [IPython rich display system](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb) to work on my custom classes. I've done it before but now I'm missing something.

This displays HTML code correctly:

```
import IPython.core.display
from IPython.display import display, HTML
HTML('<b>hey</b>')
```

but this does not:

```
class FooBase(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class FooHTML(FooBase):
    def _repr_HTML_(self):
        return '<span><b>FooHTML</b> x=%s</span>'%x

foo1 = FooHTML('hey')
foo1
```

I just get this:

```
<__main__.FooHTML at 0x83fb160>
```

What am I missing? I'm running IPython 1.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! Dumb typos. It's `_repr_html_`, not `_repr_HTML_`, and I forgot to use `self` in `self.x`.

```
class FooBase(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class FooHTML(FooBase):
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return '<span><b>FooHTML</b> x=%s</span>' % self.x
```